# Converting Mat to Keypoint?

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion, computer-vision, surf

I'm writing both descriptors (SurfDescriptorExtractor output) and keypoints (SurfFeatureDetector output) to an XML file.
Before writing keypoints (std::vector) conversion to Mat is done ( following this: [convert keypoints to mat or save them to text file opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643342/convert-keypoints-to-mat-or-save-them-to-text-file-opencv/14898185) ). For descriptors isn't neccesary, they're Mat already.
So both are saved as Mat, there's no problem on reading either. But when using a FlannBasedMatcher, and then drawMatches, this method asks for keypoint data.

The question is: how would you convert Mat to Keypoint's vector, and which would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this by looking at OpenCV source (under /modules/java/generator/src/cpp/converters.cpp, around line 185):

```
void Mat_to_vector_KeyPoint(Mat& mat, vector<KeyPoint>& v_kp)
{
    v_kp.clear();
    CHECK_MAT(mat.type()==CV_32FC(7) && mat.cols==1);
    for(int i=0; i<mat.rows; i++)
    {
        Vec<float, 7> v = mat.at< Vec<float, 7> >(i,0);
        KeyPoint kp(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], (int)v[5], (int)v[6]);
        v_kp.push_back(kp);
    }
    return;
}
```

And I'm using it as:

```
vector<KeyPoint> mat_to_keypoints(Mat* mat) {

    vector<KeyPoint>  c_keypoints;

    for ( int i = 0; i < mat->rows; i++) {
        Vec<float, 7> v = mat.at< Vec<float, 7> >(i,0);

        KeyPoint kp(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], (int)v[5], (int)v[6]);

        c_keypoints.push_back(kp);

    };

    return c_keypoints;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how the [opencv source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) does the conversion in **Java**, I couldn't find this conversion in C++, it might not exist. You might be able to translate this to C++, it is not very complex.

```
 //Code from Opencv4Android: utils/Converters.java
 public static void Mat_to_vector_KeyPoint(Mat m, List<KeyPoint> kps) {
        if (kps == null)
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Output List can't be null");

        int count = m.rows();
        if (CvType.CV_64FC(7) != m.type() || m.cols() != 1)
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
                    "CvType.CV_64FC(7) != m.type() ||  m.cols()!=1\n" + m);

        kps.clear();
        double[] buff = new double[7 * count];
        m.get(0, 0, buff);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            kps.add(new KeyPoint((float) buff[7 * i], (float) buff[7 * i + 1], (float) buff[7 * i + 2], (float) buff[7 * i + 3],
                    (float) buff[7 * i + 4], (int) buff[7 * i + 5], (int) buff[7 * i + 6]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, just found an existing c rewrite by looking at the opencv source!